# Extract value from tag python

Tags: python

How can i extract the value of name4 from the following? the example provided is a sample ? how can i do the same with xml.parsers.expat, i am using python 2.4 that doesnt have xml.etree

```
<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux">
</test>
```

Comment: You mean just getting the value from a string? Then I would do something like '<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>'.split('name4="')[1].split('"')[0], but a regex is probably cleaner.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i was not able to post sample xml so i did a bit of google then i posted :-)

Comment: as you see in answers you've got lots of choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's really easy to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

your_string = """<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>"""

soup = bs(your_string)
res = soup.findAll('test')
for i in res:
    print i.get('name4')
```

Also you can find more examples on documentation [page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

**Update** how to change name of attribute and print whole xml:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

your_string = """<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>"""

soup = bs(your_string)
s = soup.test
s['name4'] = 'Ubuntu'
print soup
```

Comment: How can i set name4 to a new value say "ubuntu" and print the whole xml ??

Answer (score 4):

using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/)

```
import lxml.html as lh

doc=lh.fromstring('<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>')

doc.xpath('.//@name4')
Out[298]: ['Linux']
```

Note1: regex can be used for this simple example but using regex to parse xml/html is a bad practice and you should not get into a habit of doing so.

Note2: if you are to into installing `lxml`, `xml.etree.ElementTree` is as good (lightweight?) alternative that comes with python, especially for simpler tasks.

Comment: how can i do with xml.etree.ElementTree i am using windows i find difficult to lxml in windows plz help

Comment: lxml works fine on windows, for xml.etree.ElementTree see, Fuzzyfelt's answer below...

Comment: http://lxml.de/installation.html , this should guide you through the process. there are binary packages available for windows, i suggest you choose one of them

Comment: @root i will work on it i think the installation procedure is a bit complicated :-)

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml has binaries that should be easy to use...

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

dom = parseString('<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>')

xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('test')[0]

print xmlTag.getAttribute("name4")
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer ElementTree as it's installed by default on many distributions, including RedHat/CentOS >= 5, and is simple to use. (lxml is far superior in functionality however)   To use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

elem = ET.fromstring('<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>')
name4 = elem.get("name4")
```

Comment: How can i set name4 to a new value say "ubuntu" and print the whole xml ??

Comment: `elem.set("name4", "ubuntu")` and `ET.dump(elem)` or `xml = ET.tostring(elem)`. See http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm

Comment: @SandeepKrishnan you can show your appreciation by upvoting my answer or comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You also use module re:

```
import re
pat = re.compile('name4="(.*?)"')

text = '<test name1="" name2="" name3="0.0.0.0" name4="Linux"></test>'
pat.findall(text)
```